# what could be the reasons for shell scripts kill itself?

Tags: shell-script, python

I have shell scripts like

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;do
   #Code HERE!
   #Pushing Data to DB
   echo "Data to DB"> /root/schip.log 2>&1
done
```

This is script is continuously running and gathering info on server and then sending data to DB(TimeStamp DB). I don't why, sometimes the scripts are dieing. In logs I can't see any thing. In same way, I saw in Python script. Python script like this

```
import <stuff>
while True:
   #Code HERE
   #Push data to DB
   print "Data to DB"
```

So, what could be the reasons?, how do I prevent? and how can I enable the logs(In python and Shell) to know the reason?. Thanks!

Comment: do any of the scripts have `set -e` in them?  if so, then any error or any non-zero exit code from any command (e.g. while shoveling data into the db) would cause the script to exit.

Comment: No, there no `set -e` in scripts. In Python script, I'm using `potsdb` module to push data to Time stamp DB like this `metrics = potsdb.Client(<serverIP><serverPort>)` then `metrics.send(<metrics_name>, <Tag1=value1>)`. So, there could be problem while pushing to DB?

Comment: So, what was it in the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things that may cause a shell to exit (not exhaustive):

- calling the `exit` utility. Let's not forget about the obvious
- calling the `return` utility. In the case of `bash` that will return only if in a function or sourced file.
- `exec cmd`. That will execute `cmd` in the same process so in effect breaking out of that loop. The script will end when `cmd` exits.
- `set -e`/`set -o errexit` is enabled (see also the `SHELLOPTS` environment variable for `bash`) and a command exits with an error.
- `set -u`/`set -o nounset` is enabled and an unset variable is referenced.
- a `DEBUG` or `ERR` trap is defined that calls `exit`.
- Failing *special* builtins. Failure of special builtins (like `set`, `:`, `eval`...) causes the shell to exit. In the case of `bash` though, that only happens in POSIX mode (like when POSIXLY_CORRECT is in the environment or when invoked as `sh`...) and even then not for all special builtins. For instance `: > /` will cause the shell to exit.
- as [mentioned by @schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238943), syntax error (like in code that is only reached conditionally).
- division by 0 (in `$((1/x))` or `${array[1/x]}`).
- internal `bash` error for instance because some limit is reached:

  - fails to allocate memory
  - fails to fork a process
  - stack size exceeded (for instance when using function recursion)
  - Some other *limits* in place via `ulimit` (which may also cause some signals to be sent).
- killed by a another process. Another process can call `kill()` to explicitly kill the interpreter of your script.
- killed by the system.

  - SIGINT/SIGQUIT. If you press `^C`/`^\`.
  - SIGHUP. If the terminal is disconnected.
  - SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGILL. The bash command does something wrong (a bug) or failing hardware (memory).
  - SIGPIPE: builtin (`echo`, `printf`) writing to a now-closed pipe or socket (could also happen for error messages if stderr is a pipe).

The first thing to check would be the error messages and the exit status.

Answer (score 0):

A syntax error in a script will terminate the script.

If your script code includes shell variables that may include spaces in some cases, this may cause a syntax error in case the shell variable is not enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Script is not terminating because of syntax error, I checked. I removed `while` statements and then I executed->Works Fine!. Actually, I ran those script with `nohup` like `nohup sh script.sh &`, that will create the `nohup.out`. I can `tail -f nohup.out` to view the data weather, it is running or not->This is also works fine(But suddenly it dieing! somtime)

Comment: You are mistaken: even with bash, scripts terminate from a syntax error. You may try to `set -x` to get the location in the script that aborts.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your Shell is sourcing some external code with the "." command.
That code is interpreted by the same shell instance. If that code has a syntax error or that code  performs an "exit", the  calling script halts. 
It is possible that this script is not called at each loop so your job is running a while before it fails.

example with a syntax error that will fails after 3 loops

```
#!/bin/sh
i=3
while true
do
let i=i-1
[ $i -eq 0 ] && . ./a 2>/dev/null

sleep 2
done
```

"a" script is missing "fi"

```
if  true
then 
   echo a
```